# Help with joint distribution functions.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $f_{XY} (x,y)=f_{1}(x,y)+f_{2}(x,y)$

where $f_{1}(x,y)=\frac{1}{198}$ for  $0≤x≤3,0≤y≤2$ and $0$ otherwise.

and $f_{2}(x,y)=\frac{1}{66}$ for for $0≤x≤8,0≤y≤8$  and $0$ otherwise

First part of the question was to find $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ for  $0≤x≤3$  and  $0≤y≤ 2$, which I got  $\frac{xy}{198}+\frac{xy}{66}$, straightforward enough.

For the second part asks for $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ for $3≤x≤8$  and  $0≤y≤ 2$, can't seem to get the right limits though, if someone could hint please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, we have
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y f_{X,Y}(s,t)\,ds\,dt.$$

So we need to integrate $f_1(s,t)+f_2(s,t)$ over the part of the plane that is below and to the right of the point $(x,y)$. Draw a picture.

Suppose that $y\le 2$ and $3\le x\le 8$. Since $f_1(s,t)=0$ when $s\gt 3$, the integral of $f_1$ over our region is $\frac{3y}{198}$.

The integral of $f_2$ over our region, more simply, is $\frac{xy}{66}$.

Add. We get $\frac{3y}{198}+\frac{xy}{66}$, which can be simplified.

Comment: could you explain how to find E[XY], I got E[x] and E[y]. I thought you should times by xy and integrate between minus infinity and infinity?

Comment: Basically yes. I cannot answer this in full detail in a comment. We want the double integral of $xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Divide the $8\times 8$ square into $4$ rectangles, using the lines $x=3$ and $y=2$. Over each part the joint density is constant (different constants). Integrate over each part separately, and add up.